# why tesseract fails for this image?

Tags: java, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

[image]

I've tried tesseract on this image and some scanned images with some text inside rectangles. but it fails each time with some garbage text as output. and correct without boxes around text. please tell me what to do with image or tesseract ? please help

Comment: post whatever you have tried..

Comment: i have tried removing rectangles using its pixel value .

Comment: he he :D .. ithe marathi allowed ahe ka? btw mala yacha uttar mahit nahi kaaran mi tesseract var kaam kela nahi. Sorry!

Comment: are fakt he boxes kashe remove karayache te sang please

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract converts the image to grayscale before classification, so the pink lines are probably being picked up as text.

Extract only the black pixels from the image, and you should be fine. You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for this.

Comment: tried on black boxes also but the result is same. Tesseract is not penetrate through the outside box. what should i do???

Comment: You'll need to remove the boxes, not make them black.

Comment: Coded in java a [RGBImageFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/RGBImageFilter.html) could be used, the [jhlabs](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/) site seems to offers a ThreshHoldFilter for removing the rectangles. For an example on ImageFilter do a search.

Answer (score 0):

As said before,  you should get rid of pink lines  before doing OCR (  they are still usefull
as character boundaries though )

Once you extacted your gliphs and binarised them ( converted to bit image )  you may start to 
use tesseract on it.  Keep in mind that tesseract uses shape extraction approach and depends on dictionary support -  you may get better results (and faster processing times)  with invariant moments like Hu

In case you are interested in java base approach, here is our OCR library doing just this in pure java (can be ported to other languages) :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

Comment: thanks but could you tell me image processing method to remove or detect these boxes coz i have to process images with such fields.

Comment: That is basic image procesing stuff.  Walk through image and check pixels for color - if their hue is off b&w discard them.  You may also compute integral inmages ( sum of all pink pixels in the same y-coordinate - it will give you peaks were you have to slice gems)  I would recommend to get your gonzalez (or comparable book) out.  You may also look at samples provided in javaocr porject there could be some clues for you